# Simple creation of table and inserting value to it

Tags: mysql

### I Want to create a table in MySql for which has a column for `Time`

---

Value for time column must accept like `9AM to 10PM`

```
+-----------------------------+
| DATE                        |
+-----------------------------+
| 9AM to 10PM                 |
+-----------------------------+
```

- **Which datatype should i use ?**
- **If i don't want to use varcar & If i can use `TIME data-type-` How to represent values there ?**
- **I am looking for create table and insert statement  as an answer for above specifications ?**

**I am a newbie so please go easy with answers**

*Thanks !*

Comment: Why cant you use varchar to store the string 9AM to 10PM and later convert it to time datatype? And you cant store such string value in Time datatype. If you really want to store such time then I would suggest create 2 columns FromTime & ToTime with time datatype and store 9AM and 10PM separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above in comment the table structure would be:

```
Create Table YourTable
(
FromTime Time,
ToTime Time
)
```

Now Insert values as below:

```
Insert into yourTable
VALUES(TIME(STR_TO_DATE('09:00 AM', '%h:%i %p')),TIME(STR_TO_DATE('10:00 PM', '%h:%i %p')))
```

Comment: Thanks :) ... final question .. Can i also modify like ................. '09 AM', '%h %p' ...... ?

Comment: no u need to follow the proper format like 9:00 AM. You can check STR_TO_DATE function for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use Time Data Type to save Time.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert `9AM to 10PM` in `datetime` datatype column.

you have to use datatype whose representation should be like string, like `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you need based on what you've described - if you could provide a little more context we might be able to offer you more insight?

But as @rkp has mentioned, if you want the time interval to be represented as "9AM to 10PM", you will have to use some form of string/text field e.g. varchar

Alternatively, depending on how you plan to use this data, you could also use two fields - one for start time and one for end time. It would probably then be recommended that you use a datetime field since this will allow for much more flexibility (e.g. when calculating differences between time periods etc)

For reference - these are your options:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html